# Tax Refund after deadline [U.S.A]

Tags: taxes, income-tax-refund

I did not submit my tax refund copy this year until the deadline (earlier this month). I don't owe taxes, but I was getting some tax refunded to me. Is it possible to get the tax refund if you miss the deadline for sending the documents to HRS?

Att

Comment: It would be helpful if you tagged the question with a tax jurisdiction (Brazil?)

Comment: Oh OK. I'm in the US though.